# How does one check for availability of vGPU for WSLg?

Tags: linux, windows-10, gpu, wsl2

I'm using latest Windows 10 insider Dev build, with the [newly introduced WSLg](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wslg-architecture/) which offers GUI for Linux applications installed on WSL2.
I'm looking for a way to verify the availability of vGPU in the host and guest OSes.

*all I've found is that the GPU driver installed on host must support WDDM 3.*

Comment: Doesn't `dxdiag` show the WDDM version of the driver? On the guest `glxinfo` or so can probably tell the mesa driver you are using.

Comment: @TomYan dxdiag shows WDDM 3 version for my Intel driver on host OS. the thing is, since i'm using insider build, I have a newer version of Intel GPU driver installed from Windows update, but that article is pointing to an older version of Intel GPU driver. so I don't know whether I should uninstall it and replace with older one or not. that's why I'm looking for a way to verify vGPU availability. I'm using Debian, entering glxinfo in the command line says command not found.

Comment: There's the package mesa-utils (and mesa-utils-extra that consists of a `eglinfo`).

Comment: Most likely you'll need a kernel and mesa package that has the support built installed as well. I doubt that they exist in an official debian repo at the moment though.

Comment: is it possible to verify this capability on host?

Comment: The article seems to imply that WDDM 3 is the indication that the host is ready.

Comment: Thanks, well I'm going to test this now, apparently this one is ready for WSLg.
https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9P9Q5ZH1HRR0

Comment: @Sam - Sounds like an answer.  Be sure you screecap the page so future readers will understand when the page no longer exists

Comment: Any hope these drivers will work for Bootcamp users?